# Python web scraping without selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, economics

I'm trying to scrape the export price with year and month breakdown
Is there a way to download from the site below without using selenium? I'd rather avoid it if possible.
The site even has an excel download button

http://www.ipcva.com.ar/olap/show_pivot.jsp?query=total

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

url = "http://www.ipcva.com.ar/olap/show_pivot.jsp?query=total"
df = pd.read_html(StringIO(requests.get(url).text))[0].droplevel(0, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               Tiempo              Pais            Cortes  Importe u$s  Cantidad Kg.  U$S/Ton.
0  Todos los Periodos  Todos los Paises  Todos los Cortes  54949576124   20329200522      2703
```

---

EDIT: To get all Years/Months:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

url = "http://www.ipcva.com.ar/olap/show_pivot.jsp"

with requests.session() as s:
    # get cookies
    s.get(url + "?query=total")

    # click on "drill member button"
    r = s.post(
        url, data={"toolbar01.drillMember.x": 0, "toolbar01.drillMember.x": 0}
    )
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    # expand "Todos los Paises" (commented out - the resulting df is huge)
    # name = soup.select_one(
    #     'div:not(:has(div)):-soup-contains("Todos los Paises") input'
    # )["name"]
    # r = s.post(url, data={name + ".x": 0, name + ".y": 0})
    # soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    # expand "Todos los Periodos"
    name = soup.select_one(
        'div:not(:has(div)):-soup-contains("Todos los Periodos") input'
    )["name"]
    r = s.post(url, data={name + ".x": 0, name + ".y": 0})

    while True:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
        inp = soup.select_one('th:nth-child(1) input[src$="expand.gif"]')

        if not inp:
            break

        print("Opening", inp.parent.text)
        name = inp["name"]
        r = s.post(url, data={name + ".x": 0, name + ".y": 0})

    df = pd.read_html(StringIO(r.text))[0].droplevel(0, axis=1)
    df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Creates `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andrej but is there any way to get the breakdown per year and per month? If you look into the website, if you click the (+) sign in "Todos los periodos" it will open the years and if you click in the (+) again for the year it will open the months available. I was trying to get the data for all years and all months.

Comment: @gnark See my edit.